# SharePoint XSLT Problem -

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to do some highlighting on some SharePoint XSLT Results.  BElow is the XML that i am getting.
The Problem that i am getting is that the Template Match blocks are not matching the child nodes of UM  If someone can see where i am going wrong that woould be great.

Thank you

Chhris

```
        <rows>
          <row>
            <LastModifiedTime>02/25/2010 18:32:25</LastModifiedTime>
            <RANK>325</RANK>
            <TITLE>UMUK Win At The Mobile Entertainment</TITLE>
            <AUTHOR>SVR08-002\Administrator</AUTHOR>
            <CREATED>02/25/2010 18:32:22</CREATED>
            <PATH>http://svr08-002:7005/Lists/FrontPageNews/DispForm.aspx?ID=3</PATH>
            <HitHighlightedSummary>a
              <c0>UM</c0> UK won the category of Best Music Label 2009 at the 4th annual ME (Mobile Entertainment) Awards C <ddd/>
            </HitHighlightedSummary>
          </row>
        </rows>
```

and here is the XSLT that i have so far.

```
          <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

        <xsl:template match="/">

          <table class="ICS_SearchTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <xsl:for-each select="rows/row">

              <xsl:variable name="Ext">
                <xsl:call-template name="get-file-extension">
                  <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-before(PATH, '?')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:variable>      
              <tr>
                <td width="10%">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="ICS_SearchResultItem">
                        <div class="ICS_SearchResultItemImage">
                        <img src="/Style Library/UMIGlobe/Styles/Images/Common/umgi-{$Ext}.png" alt="{$Ext}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ICS_SearchResultItemTitle">
                                    <a href="{PATH}"><xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ICS_SearchResultItemDesc">
                      <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="HitHighlightedSummary[. != '']">
                         <xsl:call-template name="HitHighlighting">
                            <xsl:with-param name="hh" select="HitHighlightedSummary" /> 
                         </xsl:call-template> 
                      </xsl:when>   
                       <xsl:when test="DESCRIPTION[. != '']">
                          <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>     
                       </xsl:when>     
                      </xsl:choose>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ICS_SearchResultItemLink">
                                    <a href="{PATH}"><xsl:value-of select="PATH"/></a> - <xsl:value-of select="AUTHOR" /> - <xsl:value-of select="LastModifiedTime"/>
                      <xsl:call-template name="DisplaySize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="size" select="SIZE" />
                      </xsl:call-template>                                          
                        </div>                                                                              
                            </div>                                  
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>  
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="HitHighlighting">
          <xsl:param name="hh" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$hh"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ddd">
          &#8230;
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c0">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c1">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c2">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c3">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c4">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c5">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c6">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c7">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c8">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="c9">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </b>
        </xsl:template>  

      <!-- The size attribute for each result is prepared here -->
      <xsl:template name="DisplaySize">
        <xsl:param name="size" /> 
        <xsl:if test='string-length($size) &gt; 0'>       
         <xsl:if test="number($size) &gt; 0">
         -
          <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="round($size div 1024) &lt; 1"><xsl:value-of select="$size" /> Bytes</xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="round($size div (1024 *1024)) &lt; 1"><xsl:value-of select="round($size div 1024)" />KB</xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="round($size div (1024 * 1024))"/>MB</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>    
         </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>  

        <xsl:template name="get-file-extension">
          <xsl:param name="path" />
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains( $path, '/' )">
              <xsl:call-template name="get-file-extension">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after( $path, '/' )" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains( $path, '.' )">
              <xsl:call-template name="get-file-extension">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after( $path, '.' )" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <!-- SET THE PATH IMAGE SRC -->
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$path = 'uk' or $path = 'org' or $path = 'com' or $path = 'net' or $path = 'biz' or $path = 'gov'">
                  <xsl:text>url</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$path" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>  
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "child nodes of UM"?

Maybe I'm missing something, but there are no nodes named "UM", just text. So do you mean that you want to match the node that contains the text "UM"... in other words `<c0>UM</c0>`?

In my case, when I run your stylesheet, it does match the `<c0>` node, and writes a `<b>` node.

> `<b>UM</b> UK won the category of Best Music Label 2009 at the 4th annual ME (Mobile Entertainment) Awards C`

What's not working for you?